# Not able to select autocomplete value by using selenium in mobile web

Tags: selenium, appium

I have a code to select the value from a autocomplete value ,code is properly working in the desktop browser but not working in the mobile browser ,in mobile browser it is not clicking the value i have tried using the action class also but still its not working

my code without action class.

```
List<WebElement> optionsToSelect =autoOptions.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
                        if (option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(textToSelect)) {
                            option.click();
                            break;
                        }
```

my code with action class.

```
List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = autoOptions.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
                    for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
                        if (option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(textToSelect)) {

                            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Asp')]]")).click();
                            //option.click();
                            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                            actions.moveToElement(option).perform();
                            actions.click().build().perform();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

can any one help me on this

Comment: are you using same desktop browser code for appium or you have changed the selectors for mobile browser ?

Comment: its not responsive web so i am using same selectors

Comment: can you check in UIAutomatorviewer tool if it displays same locator to identify the element. if it is different for mobile browser then change your code accordingly

Comment: can UIAutomatorviewer tool  use for browser ??

Comment: You can use it for getting any element on mobile screen and can be used for mobile browser also.

Comment: not getting its in a frame.

test site is http://demoqa.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127346/discussion-between-abhinav-and-nikhil-surendran).